# How to zero pad all states per date and case type where cumulative covid-19 cases are 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have collected data for Covid-19 per state in India. The first date is 2020-03-10, regardless of case_type. For each day, the API returns only the set of states which have cumulative cases > 0. Therefore I want to zero pad all states in the DataFrame per date and case_type where they have not had any cases yet.

```
   Date       |            State           |   Case_Type  |    Cases
2020-03-10                 Delhi               Confirmed        4
2020-03-10    |            Delhi           |    Deaths    |     0 
   ...                     ...                   ...           ...    
2020-03-26      Andaman and Nicobar Islands     Confirmed       1
```

So in the example, Andaman and Nicobar Islands had its first confirmed case 2020-03-26, therefore I want to add one row for each Case_Type per date from 2020-03-10 -> 2020-03-25 where Cases = 0. I want to do this for each State and Case_Type.

```
   Date       |            State           |   Case_Type  |    Cases
2020-03-10                 Delhi               Confirmed        4
2020-03-10    |            Delhi           |    Deaths    |     0 
   ...                     ...                   ...           ...    
2020-03-10      Andaman and Nicobar Islands     Confirmed       0
2020-03-10      Andaman and Nicobar Islands      Deaths         0
2020-03-11      Andaman and Nicobar Islands     Confirmed       0
   ....                    ....                  ....
2020-03-26      Andaman and Nicobar Islands     Confirmed       1
```

I tried the following solution, but it does not do what I want.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')\
    .groupby(['State','Case_Type'], sort=False)['Cases']\
    .resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)\
    .reset_index()
df.sort_values(by=['State','Case_Type','Date'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
```

It did not pad the dates 2020-03-10 -> 2020-03-26 for Andaman and Nicobar Islands.

Anyone have any idea of how to do it correctly?

EDIT: Changed column names so that they align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Pivot and melt. Probably not the best solution but will work fine for small dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
Date|State|Case_Type|Cases
2020-03-10|Delhi|Confirmed|4
2020-03-10|Delhi|Deaths|0
2020-03-26|Andamanand Nicobar Islands|Confirmed|1
"""

output = io.StringIO()
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = "|")

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Cases', index=['State', 'Case_Type'], columns = 'Date').reset_index().fillna(0) # Pivot data to get all dates in columns, missing values with zero
df2 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars = ['State', 'Case_Type'], value_vars = df1.columns[2:]) # unpivot data for all dates
```